# Using a "getter" as a default value of a python function

Tags: python, default-arguments

I found out this very weird behaviour in python's default values in functions and I'd appreciate any help on the reasons why I get two different behaviours on seemingly the same thing.

We have a pretty straightforward custom int class:

```
class CustomInt(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0):
        self._val = int(val)
    def increment(self, val=1):
        self._val +=val
        return self._val
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._val)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'CustomInt(%s)' % self._val
    def get(self):
        return self._val
```

Class instantiation:

```
test = CustomInt()
```

Then we define our function accepting a **getter** as a default argument

```
def move_selected(file_i = test.get()):
    global test
    test.increment()
    print(file_i)
    print(test)
```

If we hit `move_selected()` once, we get a *local copy of test* (aka **file_i**) and our global variable, test, is updated (we get `0\n1`)

The default value of `move_selected()` the second time we call it **is still 0** (we get`0\n2`). Even though test was updated. If we were to explicitly write `move_selected(test.get())` the outcome is not the same (we'd get `1\n2`).

Why? Are we not supposed to pass functions as default arguments?

Comment: The function isn't the default. The value it returns is the default. `test.get()` is called when your function is defined and the value it gives becomes the default value for the argument.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, will update the post and make it more readable now that I know where the issue is

Comment: I'm curious what exactly you're *actually* going for here? If I were to see this code in a code review, absent some clear context, I'd flag it as having a lot of code smell. I realize you're doing a minimal example, but using `global` and having a potential type mismatch (is `file_i` also a CustomInt - the naming is unclear? If it is calling `get()` returns an actual int) is concerning. There may be a cleaner way to get at what you're looking for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question.

Comment: @luther It's totally a question - he wants to know why it is that the value provided as a default to the function doesn't seem to change across multiple call, when taken from an instantiated object's getter function. The behavior he expects is that it changes because that object's state changed - but it doesn't. Valid question.

Comment: @NathanielFord When luther commented, there literally was no question and not even anything like a "I want to know why". They were purely stating observations/facts.

Comment: If you read the post you’d understand what I was looking for. If you’re just looking for a question mark then it’s your fault.

Comment: I've already retracted my close vote. There really was no question before your edits.

Comment: @luther check the first edit and you’ll find the question

Comment: After re-checking, I see that edit 2 is the one I initially saw. It looks like you accidentally removed the questions from your post, and I saw the post before you reverted.

Comment: I'd advise everyone to assume people don't post on here if they don't have a question, and to remember the focus should be clarifying questions and answers asked, not re-litigating whether a question was posed correctly in the first place. I posted my comment because there was a close vote, and therefore it was in a queue. I wanted to make the case to leave it open for queue readers. I'll delete this comment later today, as it is not pertinent going forward.

Comment: @NathanielFord: It's worth pointing out that my "voting to close" comment was made automatically when I made my close vote, and it probably wasn't clear to the OP that my close vote was undone. I decided not to delete my auto-comment, because people had already responded to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it is called. The value of `test.get()` was 0 when you defined the function, so that's what it's going to be.

If you want to call the getter every time the function runs, you can do exactly that in the function body:

```
def move_selected(file_i = None):
    global test
    test.increment()

    if file_i == None:
        file_i = test.get()

    print(file_i)
    print(test)
```

Comment: Note an important implication of the default value being defined when the function is compiled is that if you set the default value to anything mutable (aka `file_list = []`), any modification to that value within the function (`file_list.append(...)`) will carry over into the next time the function is called. So doing something like `def move_selected(file_i = test)` could get you into similar-but-different trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68968852/442945) is the quick and correct way of handling this. It bears some explaining, though, why this is a best practice in Python.

Your original function has this [type signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature):

```
f(x: T) -> None
```

(Note this is a type signature, not a function definition with type hints, hence the lack of `def`).

`T` here is the type of `file_i`. (While the OP is unclear what type this is, we can satisfy ourselves by simply using `T` as a stand-in for whatever type that is.) Call sites of function `f` will have something along the lines of:

```
t = T()  # t is created
# ... other code
f(t)
```

The question revolves around how to do this at a call site:

```
f()  # No argument provided.
```

To allow this, the new function signature changes to:

```
f(x: Option[T]) -> None
```

In Python, the way this is handled is via [`default arguments`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values). So, we might say something like this to provide a default argument to `f`:

```
t = T()
def f(x: T = t) -> None:
    # ... our function
```

When the program runs, at the point that `def f...` is executed and the function `f` is 'defined', `t` has been resolved to a concrete value, so this works. The OP has a somewhat more nuanced question though - what if we want the value of `t` to be dynamic *at runtime*? That means that when the program reaches the call site (recall `f()`) it *then* resolves the value of `t`.

The 'natural' common-sense attempt would be something like this:

```
def h() -> T:
    t = T()  # or however you want to dynamically create this.

def f(x: T = h()) -> None:  # Instead of a concrete value, call `h()`!
    # ... our code

f()  # The call site, which relies on `h()` to fill in `x`.
```

This unfortunately *does not work* because of what happens when Python resolves the definition of `f`. It sees that it needs to assign a default value to `x` and in order to get that value it calls `h()`, which returns a value. This is a variant of the common 'gotcha' around [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

So how does one get the value of `x` dynamically during runtime? This is the crux of the question. There are some options. The common best practice is to assign a so-called ['sentinel value'](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0661/). (An aside: `None` is a common sentinel value but carries the downside of also often being a perfectly valid actual value.) A sentinel says 'we do not have a value for this, act accordingly'.

Then, within the function, we can assign an actual value. What does that look like? We will use `None` as our sentinel.

```
def h() -> T:
    t = T()  # or however you want to dynamically create this.

def f(x: T = None) -> None:  # If no value is provided, use the Sentinel.
    x = x if x is not None else h()
    # ... our code

f()  # The call site, which relies on `h()` to fill in `x`.
```

This works! And is equivalent to the accepted answer and runs in line with what you will commonly seen as a best practice. It is clear and does not require any change to any call site that called it in the original manner `f(t)`.

What about defining `h` in the default value itself? Can't we pass a function there? The first-pass answer to this is 'yes'. Let's see how that works:

```
def f(x: T = h) -> None: 
    x = x if x is not None else h()
    # ... our code
```

This works because `h` has the type `Callable[[], T]` meaning once it is called it returns a value of type `T`. Instead of using `None` as our sentinel type we are using `h` as our sentinel type. It does not run afoul of being defined too early because `h` is only called *inside* the function, each time the function is run instead of only once when the function is defined.

An high-level aside about compilation: Python will run through the code and establish all the functions, classes, etc. before ever compiling or executing code within functions. Thus, if a function signature (i.e. `def f(x: = h):` has a variable in it (`h`) it will resolve that variable before it stores that function as something that can be called elsewhere. However, it will *not* evaluate the body of the function until after it is called. That is why the above stanza works, where (`def f(x: = h())`) does not.

This has one maybe-desirable hitch, which we can see in the new function signature:

```
f(x: Union[T, Callable[[], T]]) -> None
```

That means at the call site I can do any of these:

```
f(t)  # the original way
f()  # use the default value
f(g)  # !!!
```

What is `g`? Well, `g` is any defined function with the type `Callable[[], ?]`. As long as `g` takes no arguments, our function `f` will execute it and return a value. We have no guarantee here, though that the return value (`?`) is of type `T`. This formation allows the call site to pass it's own function in to determine that value - maybe this is better given your specific use case! Maybe it's dangerous. That is decided in context.

Note that this is an easy mistake to make:

```
def f(x: T = h) -> None:
    x = x()  # location B (see below)
    # ... our code
```

Because this changes our type signature to this:

```
f(x: Callable[[], T]) -> None
```

This is different because of what happens at our call sites:

```
f(t)  # original way, now can fail because `t` is not necessarily a `Callable` and location B will break.
f()  # works
f(g)  # also works
```

All of which is to say the easiest and best way to handle this is with a sentinel, per the accepted answer.

**Footnotes**

1. I'm ignoring the OP and accepted answer's use of `global`. Why this is a bad practice is [answered elsewhere](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Ewolber/courses/110/lectures/globals).
2. We could use something other than `None` as our sentinel if want `None` to also be something our call-site can pass and expect to be used.

Example:

```
class Sentinel:
    pass

UNDEFINED = Sentinel()

def f(x: T = UNDEFINED) -> None:
    x = h() if isinstance(x, Sentinel) else x  # or several possible variations.
```

Comment: I think the most common sentinel (other than `None`) is `UNDEFINED = object()` and then `if x is UNDEFINED: x = h()`. For example [discussed here](https://python-patterns.guide/python/sentinel-object/#sentinel-objects) with references to where the standard library does that.

Comment: Sure, I merely wished to show that the Sentinel can be literally any object. Individual libraries, such as the Nasa-approved [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/main/src/attr/_make.py#L62-L91) library will often have their own sentinel objects for clarity and to allow them to implement additional features on those classes (such as custom error messages).

Comment: Even they do object identity checks, though (and no self-assignments, I think). Why do a type check instead?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. `isinstance` is the variant I put, but object identity checks work as well, and are arguably better because you don't risk someone creating some *other* sentinel that is somehow incompatible. Hence the `or several possible variations` comment.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I saw that comment, and agree. Just saying it's unusual and somewhat ugly (not a good selling point :-).

Comment: Thank you so much guys I actually learnt a lot through your discussion esp about sentinel values and how  :) Thanks for your remark on global variables too but it was solely for the sake of understanding this after-all stupid thing I did not get this Sat night. Very beautiful to see people taking some time to teach me some actual programming.

Answer (score -2):

From your question, bolded by me:

> Then we define our function **accepting a getter** as a default argument
>
> ```
> def move_selected(file_i = test.get()):
>     global test
>     test.increment()
>     print(file_i)
>     print(test)
> ```
>
> [Why doesn't it update?] Are we not supposed to **pass functions** as default arguments?

You **aren't** passing/accepting the getter/function. You're passing/accepting the **result** of **calling** that getter. Here's how to *actually* pass/accept the getter. All you have to do is move the `()` down, so the default is *actually* the getter function, and you use/call it at the later times.

```
def move_selected(file_i = test.get):
    global test
    test.increment()
    print(file_i())
    print(test)
```

Output then:

```
1
1
2
2
```

Still no idea why this was downvoted, as it shows how they didn't do what they said they intended to do, and how to do it right so that it works. Which it does, as can you see from the above output also also [try yourself online](https://tio.run/##dVBBDoIwELzzil6MbTRG48WYcPLkKxqBBWtKS9rFxNfjFpCiwT007ezMbHeaF96tOZ4a13W5vnnPLq1HW18Ncps9IEdxThhVASWTUhmFUnIPutyy502n@7EdKqA7SShLmSI93cSkVSZ3UAPBUXxYFG9SOifcAbbOxPbsMx7d@JeZz4ePjk8aMRM5aP6r1nH5lRdrtlqYWwH@mzlxEwSPlEK0E0kSxLV9giQe5QoFL5UGqYgX6DsyHj0rbTMKIqD9u2/HAId1GhcyHiy4mGOBTvO@Z4nfd9e9AQ).

Comment: This presents a different problem: is `file_i` an `int`, a `CustomInt` or a `Callable`? It's a *lot* cleaner to have the first line of your function (after global imports) be `file_i = file_i if file_i is not None else test.get()`.

Comment: @NathanielFord Huh? No, it's the `get` method. Of the `CustomInt` instance. As they intended. Edit: Ok yeah it's a callable. As it should be?

Comment: So they type of `file_i` is always a `Callable`? Or only if a default is required? Note that `CustomInt` has no `__call__` function implemented so it's going to return a wrong result at `print(file_i())` if they passed in a `CustomInt`.

Comment: @NathanielFord They should always make it a callable then, yes. I'm not sure what the issue is. They clearly stated their intention of "accepting a getter as a default argument" and I just explain that they're not doing that and how to actually do it.

Comment: You're not answering the question within the (admittedly unclearly specified) constraints provided. If my function signature is `def f(i: int) -> None` and I want to know how to provide an integer pulled from a getter function as a default value, what you have provided is a solution that changes my function to `def f(i: Union[int, Callable]) -> None`. @BatWannaBe provides a lean example of how to solve this within the constraint.

Comment: @NathanielFord I'm not answering *what* question?

Comment: @NathanielFord Still not clear what question you referred to, and I added some more clarification and a demonstration now.

Comment: The OP question. The poster asked how to get a default value for an argument of type `T` at the time of the function call when they're seeing it defined at the time of function definition. Your solution is to have them change the signature to an argument of type `U` (in this case a `Callable`). If your function originally takes an int, it's not generally a good refactor to suddenly have it take a callable just to allow a default value.

Comment: @NathanielFord As I quoted, they said **twice** that they want `T` to be the getter function. Which I then just made a reality. Yes, I changed the signature in the code, to **what they want**. Where do you get the *"function originally takes an int"* from, other than from their **mistaken** code? There's no indication for that whatsoever.

Comment: They don't want `T` to be the getter function type. They want the getter function to return a type `T` that is the same type of the argument in `move_selected()`. These are different things. The type of the default value should match the type of the argument, not the other way around.

Comment: To put it another way, if you have a function `add(x: int)`, that you use a thousand places, and you want to add a default value to it, and you want that default value to come from a dynamic function that could return different values during runtime, you would not change the signature to `add(x: Callable = f)`. That would necessitate a lot of refactoring and would change the semantic meaning of the function.

Comment: While the OP said "pass functions as default arguments" their code and the accepted answer clearly demonstrates their misunderstanding is that they wanted the *returned value from a function as the default argument*. This solution offers a way to do that if they *also* change the function argument type itself - which is not being asked for (again, see the accepted answer). The explanation of why changing the argument type is often not viable should not be confused with their minimal example. Changing function signatures has an impact, it is not imagination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236547/discussion-between-nathaniel-ford-and-dont-talk-just-code).

Comment: I've made a detailed response to the OP that includes what I've raised here. I don't think if the OP accepts an answer that answer should be ignored because 'many people accept even obviously wrong answers', in particular when that answer is correct. I'm going to leave this discussion now, as it's ceased being productive.  In the future, I'd ask you to extend everyone the benefit of the doubt that they are taking the question seriously - as seriously as you.